Which resident evil movie was it where the zombies started using machine guns?
One of the resident evil movies there was a part in a compound where the zombies where carrying guns, which one was it?

I believe it was Resident Evil: Apocalypse (2004) the one with Mike Epps. The Nemesis guy had a gun.

So... the answer is... "which RE movie didn't feature zombies with machine guns?"

Nemesis is a zombie like a battleship is a row boat

zombies means plural, so not Nemesis. Anyways he/she got the answer.

You mean the Las Plagas Undead, which where first seen in Resident Evil: Retribution. These Zombies are (maybe?) not t-Virus reanimated corpses, but controlled by the Las Plagas parasite. They are similar to the Majini that were introduced in the Resident Evil 5 game.
In the movie that are essentially dressed as Russian/Kremlin soldiers (check the fuzzy coat lapels), could drive, and fire weapons like a normal human soldier would. They appeared when the scoobies entered Umbrella's Moscow simulation, a recreation of the Red Square.



